# Derogatory Terms for Martian/Ceresian/Deimosian/etc

Tags: science-fiction, language

What are some ideas, preferably based in clever word usage, puns, or some such, for derogatory terms or slurs (of varying intensity) for the inhabits of Mars/Ceres/Deimos/Venus/Jovian moons/other celestial bodies?
 These insults should preferably not actually use any "unsavory" language
  And are meant to refer to humans living on these bodies

```
Edit: I'm just looking for ideas
```

Comment: Just to be clear, these slurs are from Earth people? I think that racism is often considered comparative, it might help to narrow things down.

Comment: This seems entirely opinion based, because how else would you decide which set of puns is the single correct answer? (also, I suggest 'red heads' for Martians)

Comment: @Giter That would be a insult to the gingers....how about dust farmers? On a more serious note, Saying whatever I decide is the cleverest is clearly opinion based.

Comment: Children come up with the best (and most hurtful) insults. Ask them. Er, check with their parent first, of course.

Comment: This question is being closed as too broad.  There's a few reasons for this.  The first is that, as a general rule, if you  have to say "I'm just looking for ideas," it suggests that you haven't given us a clear metric to decide which answers are best.  The second is that naming things and similar language related tasks are not in scope on WB.  However, you might be able to adjust this to instead ask for information on how slurs get created, with a prediliction for slurs that might span planets.

Comment: Mercurials for Mercurians, Venusburgians for Venusians, Loonies for Moon people, Warmongers for Martians, Jovian goons for natives of Jovian moons, Saturnines for natives of Saturn, Your Anusians for natives of Uranus, Neptgoonians or Sea slime for Neptunians, Titanics for Titanians, etc.

Answer (score 2):

"Alien"
Imagine being referred to as something dehumanizing. It's pretty derogatory. "But they are aliens!" That's a pretty racist thing to say.

Otherwise, "greeny" for Martians.
For the others, slurs based on the myths their celestial body was named after. All Venusians being called "sluts" and "easy", for example.

Answer (score 2):

A possible good one for just about any body other than Earth is "jelly", referring to the fact that since they were raised in very low-G environments, they have soft bones and no muscle.  Anyone from further out than the asteroid belt could be called snowmen or frosty; they're well beyond the Frost Line.

Answer (score 1):

Moonies (for moon dwellers)
Bouncers (for low grav)
Dome dwellers
Suits (for people who have to wear spacesuits to go outside their city)
Miner trash (even if they aren't miners in a place that developed for mining)
And of course the modern day: Mouth breathers (a reference to space suit O2)